# Clarification on a morin's problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

[image]

What i don't understand is why The solution to this problem says that,$$\tan\theta=\frac{m_{l}}{m_{r}}$$, isn't mass a scalar quantity?

The rest is straightforward

Comment: What does mass being a scalar quantity have to do with anything?

Comment: Idk, because you use trignometry to split direction of vectors, I might be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that things reduce to a simple equation is greatly helped by the right angle between the sticks. The normal force is the component of the force of gravity ($m_l g$) in the direction of the second stick ($m_l g sin\theta$). The friction needed to keep the right hand stick from moving is $m_r g cos\theta$. Setting the two equal to each other, you see that $g$ cancels out, and because we have accounted for the directions with the $sin\theta$ and $cos\theta$ terms, we are left with the simple expression for the critical angle:
$$tan\theta = \frac{m_l}{m_r}$$

The point here is that while the problem needs vectors in the solution, the final expression is not a vector expression (because you have computed the components). In the end, vector math is usually just a series of equations (one equation for X, one for Y, etc). We just reduced it all to one equation - helped by the right angle between the strikes.

I don't know how to explain this more clearly for you - let me know if this helps with your understanding?

Comment: OHH, i understand, when the solution bluntly stated that equation, i though it was handling it like a vector, now i understand, Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been on hold, How should have i stated it?

Comment: The problem with the way you phrased your question is that you don't really narrow down the problem you have to a specific _concept_. This site has fairly strict standards on clarity of the question - which results in Q/A that is a more valuable resource for future visitors. As it is phrased, this answer may help you - but a future visitor will not find your question in a search because it's insufficiently specific. At least that's my guess. Still - I'm glad I was able to give you a better understanding of this solution. Don't worry too much about it - hang around the site and you will learn.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, mass is a scalar quantity. To get from mass to force you have to multiply by (vector) acceleration, and consider its direction. What are the accelerations involved? Are they the different for the two sticks, or might there be a cancellation?

To find the angle from the ratio of the vector *forces*, you'd write $\tan\theta={W_l}/{W_r}$, where $W_x = m_x g$ is the weight of stick $x$.

Comment: This is a statics problem, and are in equilibrium. I know the answer, but I don't understand why it was done like this.

Comment: Bigger hint: suppose you use normal forces instead of masses.

Comment: I have posted the original solution to this question, I have posted what wasn't clear to me?

Answer (score 0):

Mass can be used in this problem two different ways.

A common sort of problem uses $F = ma$. In this problem, $F = a = 0$. So it isn't useful here.

This problem is about friction. To calculate friction, you need to know the force pressing the sticks together sideways. To get the sideways force, you need to know the weight of the sticks. For this, you need the mass.